# Atom Hydrogen: How is "run cell" used?

Tags: atom-editor, hydrogen

How is the "run cell" syntax in Hydrogen for Atom used? I placed multiple

`# %%`

tags throughout my code following the official manual [here](https://nteract.gitbooks.io/hydrogen/content/docs/Usage/GettingStarted.html), but when I press Shift+Enter in between any two of the tags, it still only executes that line, not the entire cell block. I also tried the other syntax formats the manual describes, but none of them execute the whole cell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A-C-enter hydrogen:run-cell

A-S-enter hydrogen:run-cell-and-move-down

https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen/issues/304